# flat-file first row contains unwanted data--how to skip that

Tags: c#, ssis

I have multiple flat files to load in the sql server table. first couple of rows contain file path information and then I have table column listed. can anyone help me how to start reading and loading data from where the column names start. for example after the file path info my first column will be customerID. so it suppose to consider first column would be customerId. If this can be done using C# script. Please provide or refer to that script please.

Comment: In your Flat File Connection Manager, change the value of `Header rows to skip` from 0 to N. No scripting required. [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23917133/181965)

Comment: I have around 400 columns in the source and want to load 300 columns to the destination. if I un-check the first row as column, it is difficult to do the column mappings.

Comment: I need ssis to start reading the file from where the columns are starting. can I do something like that? cauz some flat files has one file path in the beginning, some has 2 file paths and some has three. And i dont want to skip that start reading columns only.

Answer (score -2):

In the Flat File Connection Manager, check the box labeled, "Column names in the first row".

[image]